# How to correctly pass formulas associated with a variable name with random effects into fitted regression models in `R`?

Tags: r, stan

I currently have a problem in that I have to pre-specify my formulas before sending them into a regression function. For example, using the `stan_gamm4` function in `R`, we have the following example:

```
dat <- mgcv::gamSim(1, n = 400, scale = 2) ## simulate 4 term additive truth
## Now add 20 level random effect `fac'...
dat$fac <- fac <- as.factor(sample(1:20, 400, replace = TRUE))
dat$y <- dat$y + model.matrix(~ fac - 1) %*% rnorm(20) * .5

br <- stan_gamm4(y ~ s(x0) + x1 + s(x2), data = dat, random = ~ (1 | fac), 
                 chains = 1, iter = 200) # for example speed
```

Now, because the formula and random formula were specified explicitly, then if we call:

```
br$call$random
> ~(1 | fac)
```

We are able to retrieve the form of the random effects.

NOW, let us then leave everything the same, BUT use an expression for the random part:

```
formula.rand <- as.formula( '~(1|fac)' )
```

Then, if we did the same thing before, but with `formula.rand` taking the place, we have:

```
br <- stan_gamm4(y ~ s(x0) + x1 + s(x2), data = dat, random = formula.rand, 
                     chains = 1, iter = 200) # for example speed
```

BUT NOW: we have that:

```
br$call$random
> formula.rand
```

Instead of the original. A lot of bayesian packages rely on accessing `br$call$random`, so is there a way to use a variable for formula, have it pass in, AND retain the original relation when calling `br$call$random`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I haven't used Stan, this is a problem inherent in the way that R handles storing calls. You can see it happening with `lm`, for example:

```
model <- function(formula)
{
    lm(formula, data=mtcars)
}
m <- model(mpg ~ disp)
m$call$formula
# formula
```

The simplest solution is to construct the call using `substitute` to insert the actual values you want to keep, not the symbol name. In the case of `lm`, this would be something like

```
model2 <- function(formula)
{
    call <- substitute(lm(formula=.f, data=mtcars), list(.f=formula))
    eval(call)
}
m2 <- model2(mpg ~ disp)
m2$call$formula
# mpg ~ disp
```

For Stan, you can do

```
stan_call <- substitute(br <- stan_gamm4(y ~ s(x0) + x1 + s(x2), data=dat, random=.rf,
                 chains=1, iter=200),
             list(.rf=formula.rand))
br <- eval(stan_call)
```

Comment: I see! Is doing something like do.call similar to what you have above?

Comment: Is this a bug with R in general or just an inconvenience?

Comment: This is just how `match.call` works. It doesn't know that you want the contents of `formula.rand`, as opposed to the name that you passed to the calling function.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your problem is not, that stan_gamm4 could be computing incorrect results (which is not the case, from what I gather), but only that `br$call$random` refers to the variable name and not the formula. This seems to be problematic for further post-processing of the model.

Since `stan_gamm4` uses `match.call` inside to find the call, I don't know of a way to specify the model differently to obtain a "correct" `br$call$random` up front. But you can simply modify it after the fact via:

```
br <- stan_gamm4(y ~ s(x0) + x1 + s(x2), data = dat, random = formula.rand) 

br$call$random <- formula.rand
br$call$random
#> ~(1 | fac)
```

and the continue with whatever you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, this is not a problem with `stan_gamm4`. In your second example, if you then do

```
class(br$call$random)
```

you will see that it is of class `"name"`. So, it is not as if `$call` is just some list with stuff in it. In order to access it programatically in general, you need to evaluate that with

```
eval(br$call$random)
```

in order to obtain `~(1 | fac)`, which is of class `"formula"`.

Comment: Note that this assumes the `formula.rand` object is still around, and still has its original value.